# How to change the sort order of payment method Amazon in magento 2

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3.4, amazon-payment

I want to change the sort order of the Amazon payment method.

By default, it comes to the first place. I need to display it in third place.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom extension and add extend the config with this system.xml:

> app/code/Your/Extension/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="amazon_payment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="8" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <group id="options" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <field id="sort_order" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Sort Order</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Sort order of Amazon Pay in the list of payment methods during the final step of checkout.]]></comment>
                        <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                        <config_path>payment/amazonlogin/sort_order</config_path>
                        <depends>
                            <field id="amazonloggin">1</field>
                        </depends>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Flush the cache and reload, the option should now be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following system config, so that you can able to edit sort order from admin.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="amazon_payment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="8" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <group id="options" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                        <label>Sort Order</label>
                        <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                        <config_path>payment/amazon_payment/sort_order</config_path>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Looks like:
[image]

By default, the sort_order value is 1. You can check the following config file:

> vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/etc/config.xml

Comment: Does not work. The sort order is getting shown but it does not apply the order.